# MYSQL Memory Usage

Tags: mysql, memory, workbench

I have MySQL installed on a VPS Windows 2008 Web Server with 1GB of memory.

Is there a way of setting a maximum memory usage limit for MYSQL.

I have workbench installed if it can be done through that.

Many Thanks

John

Comment: I think so. Check for ini-file in mysql-directory. (called mycnf.ini!?) and change value, then restart mysql.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to impose a hard limit, you could do so, but you'd have to do it at the OS level as there is no built-in setting. In linux, you could utilize ulimit, but you'd likely have to modify the way MySQL starts in order to impose this.

The best solution is to tune your server down, so that a combination of the usual MySQL memory settings will result in generally lower memory usage by your MySQL installation. This will of course have a negative impact on the performance of your database, but some of the settings you can tweak in my.ini are:

```
key_buffer_size
query_cache_size
query_cache_limit
table_cache
max_connections
tmp_table_size
innodb_buffer_pool_size
```

To Plot memory usage in Linux you can easily use a script

```
while true
do
  date >> ps.log
  ps aux | grep mysqld >> ps.log
  sleep 60
done
```

if you are trying to Check for Table Cache Related Allocations
 Run “FLUSH TABLES” and see whenever memory usage goes down.

> Note though because of how memory is allocated from OS you might not
>   see “VSZ” going down. What you might see instead is flushing tables
>   regularly or reducing table cache reduces memory consumption to be
>   withing the reason.

It is often helpful to check how much memory Innodb has allocated. In fact this is often one of the first things I do as it is least intrusive. Run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` and look for memory information block